# error storing password in keychain: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /

Tags: command-line, 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to configure `saml2aws` and getting the following error.

```
error storing password in keychain: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /
```

I've already installed `gnome-keyring`

I also started `/etc/init.d/dbus start` but to no avail.

I'm running this on WSL on Windows 10.

How can I get rid of this issue?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.x without the GUI.

Comment: Are you running WSL1 or 2?  If 1: try on 2 too.  If that doesn't work: install Ubuntu in a dual-boot config because you're going way deeper than most people ever go with WSL and might need *the real thing*...

Comment: WSL1. I need to install this program on WSL so I reckon there's no solution. @Fabby

Comment: Try WSL 2 because that has its own kernel  WSL 1 is just a translation layer and does not have the full functionality of Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried preview build on my personal PC and it was buggy as. I'll wait for the normal release to come out. Hopefully that'll solve the issue.

Comment: @Fabby after the upgrade to WSL2, I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: I've migrated to Manjaro in the meantime so no longer running Ubuntu. **:-(** Please [file a bug](https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws/issues) with the package maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation the **root cause** of the problem was with Vagrant. **We cannot use the SSH connection for the following command:** `aws-vault add <name>`, launching a terminal locally and executing the command will solve the problem. You must open a terminal on the machine itself.

**Resolution Steps:**
You have two possibilities to download the `aws-vault`. With brew and wget.

**Recommended** with *brew*: `brew install aws-vault`

Or with *wget*:

1. Download AWS Vault
    `wget https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault/releases/download/v6.4.0/aws-vault-linux-amd64`
2. Install AWS Vault

```
mv aws-vault-linux-amd64 aws-vault
chmod u+x aws-vault
sudo mv aws-vault /usr/local/bin
```

3. Check AWS Vault version
     `aws-vault --version`
4. Download the pass and gnupg (used for encryption / decryption.)
     `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y pass gnupg`
5. Generates the key used for encryption / decryption.
     `gpg --gen-key`

After generating the gpg key, you will get the output like in the example below:

```
pub   rsa3072 2022-01-29 [SC] [expires: 2024-01-29]
      FD905667DE12B1678DF234272EEF7*********
```

6. Initialize the pass:
   `pass init "FD905667DE12B1678DF234272EEF7*********"`
7. AWS Vault profile creation
   Create a profile with any name and register the IAM user access key.
   After successful finishing previous point, you can create your aws-vault connection:

```
aws-vault add "<your_profile_name>"
Enter Access Key ID: ***********
Enter Secret Access Key: ***********
Added credentials to profile "<your_profile_name>" in vault
```

8. Check the created profiles.
   `aws-vault ls`
9. You can use the AWS Vault profile you created to run AWS CLI commands.
   `aws-vault exec <your_profile_name>`
10. After creation the new terminal session, you can check the existing s3 buckets in your AWS:
    `aws s3 ls`